# Group time by X minutes, splitting at X minute intervals

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of objects that I need to group into 5 minute blocks, splitting on the 5 minute roll over i.e. 0,5,10,15,20,25 minutes etc

take this list of times (dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm) for example:

```
01/01/2000 17:00
01/01/2000 17:07
01/01/2000 17:08
01/01/2000 17:09
01/01/2000 17:10
01/01/2000 17:11
01/01/2000 17:12
05/05/2012 10:45
05/05/2012 10:46
```

I need this to return:

```
01/01/2000 17:00
----------------
01/01/2000 17:07
01/01/2000 17:08
01/01/2000 17:09
01/01/2000 17:10
----------------
01/01/2000 17:11
01/01/2000 17:12
----------------
05/05/2012 10:45
----------------
05/05/2012 10:46
```

Comment: What is the question? What's the problem with what you tried?

Comment: Questions asking for code while indicating a minimal level of effort don't fare well here.  Please edit your question and add what code you have so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use GroupBy in LINQ:

```
 times.GroupBy(y => (int)(y.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute / 5))
```

Simply reduce each DateTime to the appropriate numbered 5 minute interval by dividing the total number of minutes it represents by 5.

Comment: Thanks, I'd spent ages trying to solve this, very simple solution that was taxing my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually I would approach this by first grouping by date, then iterate over all the date groups and place the different entries into 5 min time buckets. The time buckets could perhaps be implemented as a predefined `Dictionary<int,List<DateTime>>` that you add to